# How do you break up a monolithic SPA into multiple applications/frameworks?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, architecture, vue.js

Currently we have a large Angular 1 application with a number of routes and modules.  We'd like to be able to redo certain pieces of this app with the benefits of a newer framework such as Vue.js, without having to rewrite everything.  It seems simple enough to change a link that would load a route to now navigate to a new index page which loads a Vue app.

However, on the new Vue portion of the site, we still want to have the same header as the Angular parts of the site.  This header has the functionality of navigation, displaying dropdown lists, showing data and notifications for the user, etc.  It seems like we have a couple options moving forward:

1. Rewrite the header and its functionality in Vue, giving it the same styling.  For each page with its own javascript framework, we need an implementation of the header.
2. Have a single implementation of the header that can be included by whichever page needs it, regardless of framework.

Option 1 isn't very DRY, considering that you'll have to modify each header implementation when you want to make changes.  But it seems simpler than option 2, which starts to get difficult when you consider that the body of a page might have to communicate with the header (Vue.js code needs to tell Angular header to add notification, for example) unless header updates are done with something like websockets.  Also add on top of that the performance issues with potentially using multiple frameworks on the same page.

Overall our goal is to have an extendable frontend.  I don't want to be restricted to developing in framework x for a certain project.  I've done a little bit of research looking for real world examples, and came across the concept of "micro-frontends", but I haven't found too much consensus on how to solve something like this.

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-migrate-from-angularjs-to-vue-4a1e9721bea8

Comment: just wondering how big is your app? in terms of line of code or number of states.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff 33 states